# Multiple iPhones devices synced to the same iTunes, how to keep podcasts straight?

Tags: itunes, ios, apple-id

This maybe similar/related to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8868/what-is-the-best-way-to-setup-multiple-ipod-iphones-on-the-same-computer) question.

I have my iPhone and my wife's iPhone synced to the same iTunes with different accounts. I sync my podcasts to 3 most recent that have not been listened to. If we listen to some of the same podcasts then we will effectively 'hide' the ones that one has listened to from the other that has yet to listen to it.

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Downcast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/downcast/id393858566?mt=8), or the [Podcaster](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/podcaster-formerly-rss-player/id377195245?mt=8) on your device instead of using itunes for podcast management?  By using an application each device will store their settings separately.  This does have the downside that podcasts that you both listen to, would be downloaded twice.  I long ago gave up on using iTunes for podcast management, Downcast is a far better tool, in my opinion.

Comment: [Instacast](http://vemedio.com/products/instacast) is a good option as well. I'm with you -- iTunes is really not very good for managing podcasts. If you're like me, the only time you really synced with iTunes was to update podcasts. With a dedicated app, this isn't necessary.